# A conflict between gcc parallel-mode STL code and nvcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cuda, nvcc

I meet the conflict between and nvcc with gcc 4.8.4 and cuda8.0. When I compile the following code in a.cu:

```
#include <parallel/algorithm>

int main(){
}
```

with cmd:  `nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_20 a.cu -o a.o`, I got the below error message:

```
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(423): error: function "acosh(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(439): error: function "asinh(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(456): error: function "atanh(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(470): error: function "cbrt(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(486): error: function "copysign(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(505): error: function "erf(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(519): error: function "erfc(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(535): error: function "exp2(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(549): error: function "expm1(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(587): error: function "fdim(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(605): error: function "fma(float, float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(621): error: function "fmax(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(637): error: function "fmin(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(656): error: function "hypot(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(672): error: function "ilogb(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(688): error: function "lgamma(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(702): error: function "llrint(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(716): error: function "llround(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(733): error: function "log1p(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(748): error: function "log2(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(762): error: function "logb(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(778): error: function "lrint(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(792): error: function "lround(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(806): error: function "nearbyint(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(820): error: function "nextafter(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(854): error: function "remainder(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(870): error: function "remquo(float, float, int *)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(886): error: function "rint(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(900): error: function "round(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(914): error: function "scalbln(float, long)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(928): error: function "scalbn(float, int)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(948): error: function "tgamma(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/cmath(962): error: function "trunc(float)" has already been defined

33 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001e82_00000000-9_a.cpp1.ii".
```

I think it is a conflict between gcc parallel-mode STL code and nvcc.
Do you have any solution to fix it? Any info will help, thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to import isn't part of C++11, so it isn't a surprise that nvcc chokes on them.

Comment: Try a different version, I don't see those errors with the headers from gcc-5.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried gcc-5.4.0 and cuda8.0, using cmd: nvcc a.cu -o a, but I still met the same problem. And how should I do if I want to use this library and nvcc at the same time?

Comment: The usual advice in these situations is to restrict your usage of this library to .cpp modules which are compiled with the host compiler, while putting your CUDA dependent codes in .cu files as usual.  You should be able to link things together.  Use wrapper functions or similar to make the connection between the codes in .cpp files and the codes in .cu files.